# getting blank page after replacing eregi() with preg_match()

Tags: php

I am getting blank after doing following.

```
$patt="(BEGIN:|END:)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*-->(.*)";
if (eregi($patt,$v,$res))
```

was working fine,

now i have replaced above code with following

```
$patt="(BEGIN:|END:)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*-->(.*)";
   if (preg_match('#'.$patt.'#',$v,$res))
```

and now i am getting blank page.

anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: hm, [eregi()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) is case insensitive search and first thing you can do is to add `i` modifier in [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like `#your pattern#i`. Also read documentation for [differences between POSIX and PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) in PHP (especially [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php#106310) bellow).

Answer (score 2):

`eregi` is case insensitive, you need add `i`.

```
 if (preg_match('#'.$patt.'#i',$v,$res))
```